Finbuckle.MultiTenant: TenantInfo being Null in integration test under WebApplicationFactory
when I query a table with MuiltiTenant feature I get NullReferenceException
Query
 public async Task<Unit?> GetByIdAsync(UnitId id, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return await _dbContext.Units
            .FirstOrDefaultAsync(unit => unit.Id == id, cancellationToken);
    }

On this object
using Server.Domain.Units;
using Finbuckle.MultiTenant.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders;

namespace Server.Infrastructure.Configurations;

internal class UnitConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Unit>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Unit> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("lookup_units");
        builder.HasKey(u => u.Id);
        builder.Property(u => u.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                id => id.Value,
                value => UnitId.Create(value));
        builder.HasIndex(u => u.Name).IsUnique();
        builder.HasQueryFilter(q => !q.IsDeleted);
        builder.IsMultiTenant().AdjustUniqueIndexes();

        builder.Property(u => u.Name).HasMaxLength(64);
        builder.Property(u => u.DefaultContentCount);
        builder.HasData(new List<Unit>()
        {
            Unit.Create(
                UnitId.Create(Guid.Parse("F7AE4D5C-B1B7-47F0-B0A0-D98DAC374FE8")),
                "bag", null, "tenant-1")
        });
    }
}

Circumstances:

Only when IsMultiTenant is called in the following entity
Only when I performe my integration test using WebApplicationFactory

Configuration
To minimize the dependencies and isolate the problem I've configured MultiTenant as the following:
        services.AddMultiTenant<TenantInfo>()
            .WithStaticStrategy("tenant-1")
            .WithInMemoryStore(config=>
                config.Tenants.Add(new TenantInfo
                {
                    Id = "tenant-1",Identifier = "tenant-1", Name = "tenant-1",
                }))
            ;

